# win32 api transparent opengl overlay Clickthrough

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, overlay, transparent

i try to create a transparent window with opengl rendering insite. but because it is "WS_EX_TOPMOST" it will catch all mouse input how can i tell windows to ignore my window and send all inputs to the next Window in Z-order below my window.

Stuff i already tried:

1. WS_EX_LAYERED will break my opengl Rendering
2. offscreen rendring in a buffer its pretty slow because i have to use BitBlt(Sometimes i will get a software Opgengl Context)
3. WM_NCHITTEST returning HTNOWHERE

   ```
       WNDCLASSEX wc;
   memset(&wc, 0, sizeof(wc));
   wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
   wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
   wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
   wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WindowFunc;
   wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
   wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
   wc.hInstance = NULL;
   wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
   wc.hCursor = NULL;//LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
   wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)CreateSolidBrush(0x00000000);
   wc.lpszClassName = L"TESTA";
   ```

   if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) error();

   ```
   m_OverlayWindow = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE, L"TESTA", L"hello",
       WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP, 0, 0, m_DesktopRect.right, m_DesktopRect.bottom, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);


   DWM_BLURBEHIND bb = { 0 };
   HRGN hRgn = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, -1, -1);
   bb.dwFlags = DWM_BB_ENABLE | DWM_BB_BLURREGION;
   bb.hRgnBlur = hRgn;
   bb.fEnable = TRUE;
   DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(m_OverlayWindow, &bb);

   g_OverlayWindow = m_OverlayWindow;
   EnableWindow(m_OverlayWindow, FALSE);

   PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd1 = {
       sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
       1,                                // Version Number
       PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |         // Format Must Support Window
       PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL |         // Format Must Support OpenGL
       PFD_SUPPORT_COMPOSITION | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,        // Format Must Support Composition
       PFD_TYPE_RGBA,                    // Request An RGBA Format
       32,                               // Select Our Color Depth
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...................
       m_hDC = GetDC(m_OverlayWindow);
   int nPixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(m_hDC, &pfd1);
   SetPixelFormat(m_hDC, nPixelFormat, &pfd1);
   m_OpenGlContext = wglCreateContext(m_hDC);
   wglMakeCurrent(m_hDC, m_OpenGlContext);
   const GLubyte *GLVersionString = glGetString(GL_VERSION);


   glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
   glEnable(GL_BLEND);
   glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
   glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
   ```

Comment: You could try PostMessage. Check out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944(v=vs.85).aspx